# How to remove personal data from commit menu in IntellIJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, commit

Is there a way to remove personal data from IntellIJ Idea commit menu?
Because if I not specify author it will use my personal account and it's kinda awkward

[image]

Comment: That's not IntelliJ rather it is git do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have entered your personal info when you were prompted to enter Username and Email.

You can run:

`$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"`

`$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com`

And this way it will change details for future commits